# Ag-Grid column on second line of row if data exists

Tags: styling, multiline, ag-grid

I am looking to implement the free version of ag-grid for displaying about 1,000 records.  The records have about 8 columns that will display on the first row, but I would like the 9th column to display across the entire width of the row on a second line.  It would only display if data exists.  Is there a way to accomplish that with Ag-Grid?

Answer (score 0):

In the free version of AgGrid you have [Full Width Rows](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-full-width-rows/). However, you cannot have a full-width-row and a regular columns-row which both access the same data. And I assume what you are looking for is a design like this:

```
|___|___|___|___|___|
|___________________|
|___|___|___|___|___|
|___________________|
|___|___|___|___|___|
|___________________|
```

So in order to have both columns and rows, you would need to duplicate the data and do something like

```
function isFullWidth(index) {
  return index % 2 === 0;
}
```

Now if you want the full-width-row to be expandable/collapsable (I assume it is for some detail information that the 9th column is too small and you want to place an expand button in that column), you have to get ag-grid enterprise for the row-grouping or row-trees.

Our team also faced that problem (data not fitting in the column) and we went for the approach of putting ngx-bootstrap-tooltip in a column, so on hover (or hammer.js-gesture) you see a tooltip.

Comment: Your depiction of the design is exactly what I am looking for.  As more of a hobbyist programmer, I was hoping for a more easily implemented solution that doesn't involve purchasing the enterprise option.  Is there any other free grid that might provide something similar or more forwardly implemented?   I apologize in advance if this solution is easy to implement, but it's not clear to my more limited skills.

Comment: You can also check out Turbo Table from PrimeNG. But I think your best bet really is to do the hack that I mentioned or adjust your UI-design to what goes best with ag-grid's free version. The PrimeNG developers close issues without a reason so I don't like working with their framework. And I think in primeng you would also need to do a hack to have both sortable columns as well as rows in between them, but I am not sure.

Comment: Thanks Phil.  Any chance you could provide a simple sample code segment?  The JSON source is https://sfuysa.com/suspJSON.php The problem is the COMMENTS column

Comment: Hi, Is there a way to accomplish this with the enterprise version?